SAMBA share permisison error NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED
I'm trying to create a SAMBA share of a media folder of my jellyfin server, I already have a shell acces user created with ISPC user interface and I'm able to access the web folder of the website of that user through SAMBA.
I've created a new SAMBA share called media that points to /media/data/jellyfin/media but I can't do nothing in that share from my guest computer, IE, if I issue a simple ls command, I get this error NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED listing *
Is there a way to get rid of that SAMBA permisison issue?
# smbclient //XXXXXX/media -U XXXXXX
Password for [MGS\XXXXXX]:
Try "help" to get a list of possible commands.
smb: \> ls
NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED listing \*
smb: \>

Here are some permissions listing
# sudo net usershare info --long
[media]
path=/media/data/jellyfin/media
comment=
usershare_acl=XXXXXX\XXXXXX:F,
guest_ok=n

[server]
path=/var/www/clients/client1/web2/web
comment=
usershare_acl=XXXXXX\XXXXXX:F,
guest_ok=n

Permissions of jellyfin folder
# ls -la /media/data
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root    4096 jul 24 17:58 jellyfin

Permissions of media folder
# ls -la /media/data/jellyfin/
drwxr-xr-x  3 web2 client1 4096 jul 24 18:11 media

ACL of media folder
# getfacl /media/data/jellyfin/media/
getfacl: Eliminando «/» inicial en nombres de ruta absolutos
# file: media/data/jellyfin/media/
# owner: web2
# group: client1
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x


Did you use a valid users = statement in your smb.conf? As it stands, I don't think any users have access.

I have that commented ;   valid users = %S but, I have another share pointing to another path with same user and I can R/W to that share
